# Symfony 1.4 & Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, symfony1

I've an application running  on symfony 1.4 & Doctrine (1.X).
I would like to be able to use MongoDB together with the Mysql DB already setup.

Some data will be stored in the mongodb rest will remain in Mysql.
So right now I'm looking for a way to **setup mongoDB in symfony 1.4**, and get it working without impacting Doctrine connector.

Could anyone explain me how to proceed?
Only plugin found is sfMondongoPlugin and hadn't been updated since 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting query. Did you check https://github.com/Retentio/Boomgo ?

Comment: No I haven't yet. Ideal would be to use Doctrine 2 from what I've read but how to get it working together with Doctrine 1 in a same Symfony project..

Comment: I don't think, it's a good idea. But I'm also interesting in using Mongo with symfony1 but in a near future, not right now. And I think I will try to integrate Boomgo in a plugin using sfMondongoPlugin as a bootstrap. Or if you have time :)

Comment: I'm actually moving to Symfony2, things seem to be better integrated with mongodb there ;-)

Comment: Definitely, but I can't move my whole project to sf2.0, so I will take a look in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any solution and actually didn't spend enough time to find one.
Moving to SF2 definitely simplifies that process, even though symfony2 doesn't look like sf1 at all. So starting with SF2 basically means learning a new framework...